motion tracking floor orientation keeps being wonkey

i was trying to motion track this footage and add some object for the girl to be pushing an object
i got a low solve error and the track is pretty smooth but the floor and wall orientation keeps being weird, i tried to orient it manually but still trying to animate a moving object with weird xyz orientation has proved to be quite difficult
this is the motion track blend file that i did 
